# ul li display block trouble

Tags: html, css, html-lists, stylesheet

So i have two different ul lists:

```
<div class="features">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>quantity</li>
                <li>
                    <select>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                    </select>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>size</li>
                <li>
                    <select>
                        <option value="46">46</option>
                        <option value="48">48</option>
                    </select>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>color</li>
                <li>
                    <img src="img/color-white.jpg">
                    <img src="img/color-black.jpg">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><form><button class="add-button">Add to shopping list</button></form></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="social">
    <ul>
        <li>twitter</li>
        <li>facebook</li>
        <li>vkontakte</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I use this styles:

```
.features ul ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 125px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.social {
    display: block;
}
```

And I want those two lists to be one under another, but no matter how I try they always one on the left and the other on the right.

Please help me two force them to get into right position

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I can't use clear:both, because they are floated to another big image on the left

Comment: Can you set up a jsFiddle for us?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the items to automatically display on the next line you can just **remove** the    `display:inline-block` from the `.features` class and they will begin to stack on one another.

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GXuYD/)

You are also making some unnecessary `ul` and `li` structures here, which give you some borked margins. Try slimming down the lists and use only what is necessary.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Answering this without an example or complete CSS is like shooting in the dark.

You say your `ul` are floated to the right of a big image, so I assume you have something like `ul { float: right; }`, in which case they simply float up next to each other as expected.

If this is the scenario, then you can easily solve the problem by adding `clear: right;` to `.social`(or whatever the second `ul` is).